# C#, MySql Select statement

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I can't figure out what's wrong, I've checked other questions about it.
I get the following message in my textbox: "mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlcommand"

```
if (Session["Login"] != null)
    {           
        string email = (string)Session["Login"];
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringloginDb"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand getNome = conn.CreateCommand();
        getNome.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        getNome.CommandText = "SELECT nome_utente FROM utenti WHERE email = @email";
        getNome.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        getNome.ExecuteNonQuery();

        txtNome.Text = getNome.ToString();

        conn.Close();
```

etc.

Comment: You need to add .SingleOrDefault() to the end of your getNome.SingleOrDefault().ToString() or Even ExecuteScalar() depending on what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNome` is a `MySqlCommand` which doesn't override `ToString`. Therefore you get the full-type-name when you call `getNome.ToString`. You want this:

```
// getNome.ExecuteNonQuery();                    <--- not this
txtNome.Text = (String)getNome.ExecuteScalar();  <--- but this
```

( presuming that `email` is unique )

Comment: Yes, obviously you can't register on the website with the same email more than one time

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 txtNome.Text = (string)getNome.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are using the .ToString() method of the MySqlCommand type, which in this case returns the name of the class itself (inherited from objet type).

I'd suggest to use the ExecuteScalar() method instead.